# How do I disassemble this shower screen without damaging it?

Tags: shower

I need to remove the shower screen so I can refit some tiles that have failed due to water getting behind them.

As I did not put up the screen I do not know how it fits together, can anyone give me some pointers on how I take it apart.   I can see some screws but it is not clear how I get to all of them with a screw driver.

[image]

Corner from top

[image]

Corner from inside

[image]

End with door

[image]

End with fixed glass

[image]

Comment: A close-up picture of the inside of the corner joints and a downward picture of the top of the corner would be a big help.

Comment: @bib, I have added some more photos

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to be certain, but removal of the screws at the top corners should allow the top crossbar to be removed. There may be other screws that join the sections of the frame, or once the top bar is removed, the side panels may be able to slide out. The tracks against the wall are probably held in by screws hidden under the side panels.

To get to a screw in a tight space like the top corner, you can use an [offset screwdriver](http://www.homedepot.com/s/offset%2520screwdriver?NCNI-5)

[image: offset screwdriver]

You need to be careful in removing the panels. They may be heavy, and significant flexing may lead to breakage.

`Links and images are illustrative only and not an endorsement`